# Laravel 5, can't share data with view using boot in AppServiceProvider

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Just done a fresh install of L5 and, as per the documentation, i'm trying to share data with all views using a simple share method in the AppServiceProvider class.

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */

public function boot()
{
    View::share('website', 'test');
}

/**
 * Register any application services.
 *
 * This service provider is a great spot to register your various container
 * bindings with the application. As you can see, we are registering our
 * "Registrar" implementation here. You can add your own bindings too!
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(
        'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar',
        'App\Services\Registrar'
    );
}
```

}

route file:

```
Route::get('/', function(){
return view('test');
});
```

blade file:

```
<h1>Test</h1>
{{ $website }}
```

This should be really easy, so i'm wondering if i've made a very obvious mistake at the installation stage.

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem here? What isn't working?

Comment: See below. Probably there was an issue with the initial composer install. I manually deleted the vendor/compiled.php file and ran composer update again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most probably you should clear the `compiled.php` file by running:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

or by manual deleting `vendor/compiled.php` (in previous L5 versions it's `storage/framework/compiled.php`).

---

Here's the explanation. Laravel **pre-compiles** certain classes that are used on basically every request. This serves the purpose of performance optimization. Files to compile can be specified in `config/compile.php` under `files`. The [default one](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/compile.php) looks like this:

```
'files' => [
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php'),
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/BusServiceProvider.php'),
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/ConfigServiceProvider.php'),
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php'),
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php'),
],
```

That means if you change one of those precompiled files, changes won't be applied immediately (if `compiled.php` exists) but only after you run `php artisan optimize` again or after you run `php artisan clear-compiled` to clear the `compiled.php` file.

Comment: Thanks, I called that command and got an error of: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Foundation\Application::getCachedCompilePath(). So I deleted the vendor/compiled.php and ran composer update and this fixed the problem.